# Multiply values from two arrays (Artificial Neuron)

Tags: c++, arrays, artificial-intelligence, multiplication

```
////////////////////MAKE INPUT VALUES////////////////////
double *NumOfInputsPointer = NULL;
std::cout << "How many inputs?" << std::endl;
int NumOfInputs;
std::cin >> NumOfInputs;
NumOfInputsPointer = new double[NumOfInputs];
std::cout << std::endl;
double InputVal;
for(int a = 0; a < NumOfInputs; a++)
{
    std::cout << "What is the value for input " << a << std::endl;
    a+1;
    std::cin >> InputVal;
    *(NumOfInputsPointer + a) = InputVal;
}

std::cout << std::endl;

////////////////////MAKE WEIGHTS////////////////////
double *NumOfWeightsPointer = NULL; 
int NumOfWeights;
NumOfWeightsPointer = new double[NumOfWeights];
double WightVal;
for(int a = 0; a < NumOfInputs; a++)
{
    *(NumOfWeightsPointer + a) = 0.5;
}

////////////////////Multiplication BRAIN BROKE!!!!!////////////////////
double *MultiplyPointer = NULL;
MultiplyPointer = NumOfInputsPointer;
for(int a = 0; a < NumOfInputs; a++)
{
      //Stuff to do things 
}
```

The code above is going to make a single Artificial Neuron. I already have it built to make an array with the users wanted number of inputs which then automatically makes every inputs weight 0.5.

The wall I have hit, has caused me to struggle with the multiplication of the input values array with their weights array, then save those in another array to be added together latter and then go through a modifier.

My struggle is with the multiplication and saving it into an array. I hope I explained my problem well enough.

Comment: you are using `a+1;` in first for loop. use either `a=a+1;` or `a++;` if you want to do increment.

Comment: Allocate your new array just like the others and then `MultiplyPointer[a] = NumofInputsPointer[a] * NumOfWeightsPointer[a]` ?  Also read about std `vector` ...  Also note you didn't initialize `NumOfWeights` before you use it...  Is your intention for all these vectors to be the same size?

Comment: @Guy Sirton: Made the changes you suggested and it worked perfectly! Fixed NumOfWeights, and will definitely look at std::vector as well. Might help clean up my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `new` it like you did with the others, and store the result of the multiplication there.

```
MultiplyPointer = new double[NumOfInputs];
for (a = 0; a < NumOfInputs; a++) {
    MultiplyPointer[a] = NumOfWeightsPointer[a] * NumOfInputsPointer[a];
}
```

That being said, there are better ways to go about solving your problem. `std::vector` has been mentioned, which makes the memory management and looping bits easier. I would go a step further and incorporate a library with the notions of a matrix and matrix expressions, such as [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions) or [dlib](http://dlib.net).

Example using `Mat` from OpenCV:

```
cv::Mat input(NumOfInputs, 1, CV_64F, NumOfInputsPointer);
cv::Mat weights(NumOfInputs, 1, CV_64F, cv::Scalar(0.5));
cv::Mat result = input.mul(weights);
```

If the weights vector is not to be modified and reused, just skip the whole thing:

```
cv::Mat result = input.mul(cv::Scalar(0.5));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems with this code. I would highly recommend using std::vector instead of arrays. If every input has a constant weight of 0.5, then what's the point of creating an array where all elements are 0.5? Just create a constant variable representing the 0.5 weight and apply it to each input. The second array is unnecessary from what I can tell. Creating the last array (again, this would be easier with a vector) would be similar to the first one because the size is going to be the same. It is based on the number of inputs. So just create an array of the same size, loop through each element in the first array, do the multiplication using the constant I described above, and then store the result into the new array.

Comment: Thank you for the help and I am going to take time this week to grasp vectors. Seems it will really clean my code a bit. The reason there is an array for the 0.5 values, is because of back propagation. All those values will change further down the road so they need to be in an array to be altered for their respected inputs.